# Handling hash tables in custom objects

Tags: powershell

Our monitoring system has a REST API that I am trying to retrieve properties from, then output them to a custom object. A couple of the property values are hash tables.

In addition to keeping the custom objects for use in Powershell, I would like to export them to CSV, so I need those hash tables to be something else, so I don't end up with Syste.Object[] in those columns.

The object returned from the API looks like this (truncated):

```
$allServices[0]

alertStatus               : none
ignoreSSL                 : True
description               : Test service
stopMonitoring            : False
stopMonitoringByFolder    : False
useDefaultLocationSetting : False
serviceProperties         : {}
transition                : 1
alertStatusPriority       : 100000
serviceFolderId           : 1
script                    :
disableAlerting           : False
individualAlertLevel      : warn
checkpoints               : {@{id=1; geoInfo=Overall; smgId=0}, @{id=2; geoInfo=US - Los Angeles; smgId=1}, @{id=3; geoInfo=US - Washington DC; smgId=2}, @{id=4; geoInfo=US - San Francisco; smgId=3}...}
pageLoadAlertTimeInMS     : 30000
sdtStatus                 : none-none-none
serviceStatus             : alive
method                    : tabledriven
id                        : 1
```

Then checkpoints looks like this:

```
$allServices[0].checkpoints

id geoInfo            smgId
-- -------            -----
 1 Overall                0
 2 US - Los Angeles       1
 3 US - Washington DC     2
 4 US - San Francisco     3
 5 Europe - Dublin        4
 6 Asia - Singapore       5
```

What is the best way to deal with the checkpoints property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `checkpoints` (and possibly `serviceProperties`) to a JSON string.

```
$allServicesCSV = foreach ($srv in $allServices) {
    $srv = $srv.PSObject.Copy() # shallow copy
    $srv.checkpoints = ConvertTo-Json $srv.checkpoints -Compress
    $srv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the requirements changed, so I only need to output to json/XML and not to CSV, making this much easier. Thanks.